# Function does not recognize copy of array of arrays of objects in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of array of objects (from a class) which is an attribute of my component and a function that takes it as an argument.

```
myFunc(MyClass[][]) {...}
```

In another function I  modify this array of arrays. But sometimes I want to reverse the changes. I tried to to do a copy of it like that :

```
let temp = myArray.map(line => Object.assign([], line.map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj))));
```

When I log in the console it is identical. Then I replace the attribute with the copy if I need to reverse the changes. But when myFunc is called I got this :

```
ERROR TypeError: "myFunc is not a function"
```

The function works prefectly fine when I don't use a copy.
Why is it happening ?

Comment: how you call `myFunc` ? on which object, temp ?

Comment: Yes, or a copy of temp reinjected in the original array.

Comment: you think that the problem comes from the copy ? if so try https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep ... for me your error message comes from another thing that we are not seeing in your post

Answer (score 0):

You have only copied the reference. You need to copy the array to a new reference.

```
const copyOfArray = [...originalObject];
```

See also: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)